# analyzing htop data in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, htop

i am trying to find bottleneck in my server, specifically in my web application of why things are running super slow. Here is a screenshot of my htop:

[image]

As far as I can tell mysql here is almost taking all the resources of the CPU. I wonder how I can mitigate this.

Comment: There is no clear way to answer this query, but I'd start by determining if what mysqld is doing is desirable. if it isn't then you need to fix the problem in your server configuration or in the way your app is using your database.

Comment: @FrankThomas how do I determine if mysqld is doing desirable?

Comment: The mysql-performance blog, led my the folks at Percona, is a really good resource you should tap into: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/08/04/to-find-the-bottleneck-stop-guessing-and-start-measuring/

Comment: To Expound; You have one of two problems (or perhaps both): either your applications are misbehaving, due to an issue in configuration or program logic, or your server is simply under-provisioned for your needs. By analyzing what mysql is doing, you can probably determine which is the issue. if you are seeing large activity, but no issues with deadlocks or other performance affecting afflictions, then you may just need a better server. if you are seeing issues with what mysqld is doing however, you want to hone in on the specific activity and optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

If you've identified MySQL as the culprit, consider using the Percona Toolkit to identify if there are any particular queries that could be causing the problem:

http://www.ovaistariq.net/768/profiling-your-slow-queries-using-pt-query-digest-and-some-love-from-percona-server/